# Cláusula OR DIE ha dejado de funcionar

Tags: mysql, php8

Estoy migrando una aplicación a PHP 8 desde PHP 7.
Siempre tengo este tipo de sentencias para cada vez que ejecuto una instrucción a MYsql:

```
    // Abrimos consulta.
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die ("ERR1310: Error de sistema. " . $conn->error);
```

Si la consulta generaba un error pintaba el texto de la derecha. Pero ha dejado de funcionar, ahora pinta un falta error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'and p.stock_min &gt; (s.st_fisico - s.st_reservado)' at line 6 in /var/www/vhosts/pruebasphp.com/httpdocs/funciones/ex_csv.php:13
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/pruebasphp.com/httpdocs/funciones/ex_csv.php(13): mysqli-&gt;query()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/pruebasphp.com/httpdocs/f/json.php(1974): ex_csv()
#2 {main}
  thrown in <b>/var/www/vhosts/pruebasphp.com/httpdocs/funciones/ex_csv.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
```

¿Por qué?

**Postdata**

Creo que no se me entiende. He ejucutado una consulta que genera un error:

```
<?php
$sql = "select provocar error";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die ("ERR9999: Error mysql");
?>
```

Si este código lo ejecuto sobre PHP7 me pinta:

**ERR9999: Error mysql**

Si este código lo ejecuto sobre php8 me pinta:

**Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column 'probocar' in 'field list' in /var/www/vhosts/pruebasphp.com/httpdocs/borrame.php:50 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/pruebasphp.com/httpdocs/borrame.php(50): mysqli->query() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/pruebasphp.com/httpdocs/borrame.php on line 50**

Comment: Comprueba el valor de error_reporting en el phpinfo() de ambos PHP (7 y 8) y mira si coinciden. Seguramente en el 7 lo tenias deshabilitado y en el 8 no tanto.

Comment: Hola, gracias. Esto lo he sacado de dos web, una tiene 7 y otra, que de momento es la única tiene 8: Core
`PHP 8.1.2
Directive    Local Value  Master Value
error_append_string  no value  no value
error_log    /.../errores_sistema.log no value
error_prepend_string no value  no value
error_reporting   7    22519

Core
PHP 7.1.33
Directive    Local Value  Master Value
error_append_string  no value  no value
error_log    /.../errores_sistema.log no value
error_prepend_string no value  no value
error_reporting   32759   22519`

Comment: Lo que tiene error es tu consulta SQL: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; ... for the right syntax to use near 'and p.stock_min &gt; (s.st_fisico - s.st_reservado)' at line 6`. Puedes hacer una depuración imprimiéndola y revisándola. Conviene que agregues tu consulta pulsando en [edit] así como el trato que haces de ella. El `&gt;`  hace pensar que estás abusando de los filtros. pues estarías convirtiendo el símbolo `>` necesario para tu consulta en una entidad HTML. **No se debe abusar de los filtros**, luego pueden pasar cosas como estás.

Comment: Claro, de eso se trata. Antes me pintaba el error "ERR1310: Error de sistema. " . $conn->error" y con ese código lo buscaba. Si quería añadía la variable que contenía la sentencia. Pero ahora tengo que buscar a mano y hacer un echo antes de llamar al método Query., el OR DIE no funciona, debería pintar el error si no funciona la instraucción sql.

Comment: @ManuBurreroSánchez No entiendo lo que has hecho con lo que te dije del `phpinfo()`.  No debes sacarlo de **otras web** sino de la tuya. Es decir, create un archivo vacio con extensión `.php` y dentro le pones `<?php phpinfo() ?>` y lo abres con el navegador y buscas los valores del `error_reporting`.  Y eso lo haces en ambos casos, es decir, tanto en la versión 7 que dices que funcionaba como en la version 8, y comparas sus resultados.  Si son distintos pues ya lo tienes. O bien vete a los php.ini de cada una de ellas y buscalo alli y lo modificas reiniciando el motor de php que estes usando

Comment: Sí, sí, nuestro gestor de contenido (es propio) pinta la devolución de esa función en formato HTML en una lengüeta de sistema. Una es la página que tiene php8 y no funciona el OR DIE y la otra aún no se ha migrado y tiene PHP7. Ésta última me pinta bien los errores.

Comment: en la de php8 pinta: error_reporting local value: 7 y master value 22519
en la de php7 pinta: error_reporting local value: 32759 y master value 22519

Comment: Pues vete aqui para entender lo que significan: https://maximivanov.github.io/php-error-reporting-calculator/  y lo que haria seria editar el php.ini de la version 8 de PHP y pondria el valor igual que tienes en la versión 7, y luego reiniciaria el motor de PHP, claro, para que se aplique bien, a ver si con eso lo arreglamos... Y si ni con esas lo arreglamos entonces pega la consulta SQL en la pregunta, pues entonces @A.Cedano tendrá razón y tienes algun problema de conversión de caracteres a entidades html previo que en php 7 no te pasaba, pero ahora en la 8 si

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el problema. No entiendo si hablamos de un gestor de errores personalizado o de una consulta SQL que no funciona. En el error fatal que compartes en la pregunta te está diciendo que tu consulta SQL tiene error de sintaxis. ¿El problema es que no puedes hacer funcionar esa consulta o es manejando el error de esa consulta?

Comment: @A.Cedano es el manejo de los errores, el quiere que el DIE ese lo controle en lugar de escupir un error fatal (quizas tambien tiene que jugar con el display_errors supongo)

Comment: @masterguru el problema es que el código no está entrando ahí. Si el error ocurriese ahí, se imprimiría esto: `ERR1310: Error de sistema` más el mensaje de error, sin embargo, lo que se está imprimiendo es otra cosa: *`You have an error in your SQL syntax; ... for the right syntax to use near 'and p.stock_min &gt; (s.st_fisico - s.st_reservado)' at line 6`* y ese error ocurre en la línea `13` de este archivo: `httpdocs/funciones/ex_csv.php`

Comment: @masterguru antes con php7 y para atrás sí capturaba el error de mysql y al usuario le pintaba ERR9999. Cuando el usuario lo ve, me da ese nº y nosotros depuramos, ahora aparece el error típico de php. Antes eso no pasaba.

Answer (score -1):

Otra jugada más de PHP8, vaya panzada de trabajar me va a dar. en php.net ya no encuentro ejemplos OR DIE, cuando antes era habitual, entiendo que se ha de migrar a TRY-CATCH, pero no veo que nadie haya tenido tal problema, a mí me hace cambiar 1500 líneas de código.

Solución momentánea:

antes:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die ('ERR1207: Error del sistema.');
```

ahora:

```
try { $result = $conn->query($sql); } catch (Exception $e) { exit ('ERR1207: Error del sistema.' . $conn->error); }
```

Al final prepararé una función y aprovecharé para cada vez que ocurra algún error en alguna de nuestras web, mande un email a soporte:

```
function q ($sql = "", $err = "", $debug = false)
{
    global $conn;
    try 
    { 
        return $conn->query($sql); 
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    { 
    $msg = $debug ? "$err: Error del sistema." . $conn->error : "$err: Error del sistema.";
        enviar_email("Error MYSQL en " . __DOMINIO, "Error $err : $conn->error");
        exit ($msg); 
    }
}

$sql = "select provocar error";

//Formato anterior a PHP8: $result = $conn->query($sql) or die ('ERR1207: Error del sistema.');
$result = q($sql, "ERR1207");
```

Comment: Era justo lo que estaba mirando ahora, lo del die() viene del antiguo y obsoleto driver de mysql a secas

Comment: Bueno, me voy a hartar de trabajar, pero ahora con esa función depuraremos más rápido. Antes como no lo vieras en pantalla, no sabías que había un error. Ya en la documentación de php.net sobre MYSQLi, no hay referencia a OR DIE.